# Break a pandas line plot at specific date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a time-series dataframe with missing data for some time period. I would like to create a line plot and break a line where there is missing data.

```
data_site1_ave[["samples", "lkt"]].plot(figsize=(15,4), title = "Site 1", xlabel='')
```

Is it possible to create a gap, let's say from 2018-05-01 to 2018-10-30 in the line plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create arbitrary gaps by simply calling `df.plot()` several times, on the appropriate slices of the full dataframe. To make everything appear in the same plot, you can pass the `ax` keyword argument to `plt.plot()` via the `df.plot()` method. Turn the legend off for all but one call, so that the legend only has the one entry.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create sample time series
N = 365
np.random.seed(42)
x = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', freq='d', periods=N)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(N, 1) - 0.5)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['y'], index=x)

# plot time series with gap
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.loc[:'2018-05-01'].plot(ax=ax, c='blue')
df.loc['2018-10-31':].plot(ax=ax, c='blue', legend=False);
```

[image: time series plot with gap]